# Why do I get the error "The item ... may not be cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent" when trying to cloak a sub-sub-folder from a build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 to build a C# solution. Deep within the folder structure of this solution are folders containing certain large non-code data files. I would like some builds to *include* these, and some builds to *exclude* them.

Using the TFS 2015 web interface, I set up the build that should *exclude* these files. I then use the `Repository` tab and add the data folders to the Mappings section with a `Cloak` type mapping.

However, when I then queue this build, it fails with "The item ... may not be cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent".

The top-level folder in the code repository is mapped, of course. Why is TFS complaining about this, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the *why*, but I do know that to fix this problem you need to just **read the error message**:

> The item ... may not be cloaked because it does not have a mapped **parent**

So if you have ended up with this sort of repository structure in the failing build:

```
Type   Server Path                    Local Path
Map    $/Project                      $(build.sourcesDirectory)\Project
Cloak  $/Project/Assets/Data/Data2013
Cloak  $/Project/Assets/Data/Data2014
Cloak  $/Project/Assets/Data/Data2015
```

You just need to add one more line like so:

```
Map    $/Project/Assets/Data          $(build.sourcesDirectory)\Project\Assets\Data
```

Now, the items you are attempting to `Cloak` have a "mapped **parent**", and your build should succeed.

You might think that the fact that the whole repository tree is 'mapped' would be enough, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is just the accurate one for this issue. I will only add one more point which related to *why*.

In TFS, a cloaked path means the path is **not included in recursive mapping of its *parent* folder**.  When your workstation has source code in the parent's mapped directory, and the source code has not been added to  source control, the local directory is considered to be cloaked.

In simple terms, just as the error info mentioned, this is by designed, a '`Cloaked`' folder cannot be cloaked if the folder does not have a mapped parent. For more details, you could take a look at related info of *cloak* in MSDN Link: [Optimize your workspace using explicit, implicit, cloaked, and non-recursive folder mappings](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace#optimize-your-workspace-using-explicit-implicit-cloaked-and-non-recursive-folder-mappings)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ProjectXYZ / Drop ' cannot be cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent.

Another way to get this error is if you specify a Sln file in the Map:

[image]

The correct place to specify a single Sln file is in step 1 the Process.

Answer (score 0):

Check this quick solution. Solved my problem.

http://jawedm.blogspot.com/2013/05/error-in-team-foundation-server-this.html

1. In the **Source Control Explorer** window, right click the parent node
   -- the context menu appears
2. Click the **Remove Mapping**... option in the context menu -- the Remove
   Mapping dialog appears
3. Check the boxlabeled, **Recursive**
4. Click the **Change** button -- a prompt
       appears,
               stating, "Newly mapped items will not be downloaded until you
               execute a get. Do you want to get $/[PARENT PATH] now?", where
               "[PARENT PATH]' is the path of the parent node
5. Click the No button
                   -- the prompt and Remove Mapping windows disappear, and then the Get window appears
6. **CAUTION**: Use your best judgement
       here! 
           I
               decided
                   to
                       click the Cancel button in the Get progress window, to prevent
                       mapping child objects